# How to convert $project step in mongodb from dotted to nested form

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

In my database I've documents that have a `location` attribute that has data like so:

```
{location: {Country: 'Nigeria', State: 'Lagos', City: 'Victoria Island'}}
```

Please note that 'Country', 'State' and 'City' are user-defined keys/properties/attributes. The user can use a graphical interface to create the location types (the keys/properties/attributes), as such they may contain spaces or otherwise be invalid for dotted notation.

I'm currently using a `$project` step in my aggregation that's written so:

```
{$project: {location: '$location.{}'.format(location_type)}}
```

But I want to convert this into nested form. So far, doing things like

```
{location: {'$location': {'{}'.format(location_type): 1}}}
```

hasn't worked because `$location` isn't a recognized aggregation operator, and I'm still relatively new to MongoDB and aggregation.

As regards expected output, I'm only projecting the selected `location_type` so that I can group by that, so I basically want to `'$group` by a specified `location_type`, so for instance, I could project the country or the city or the state (again, purely for example sake - the location types are user-defined, so they may be called anything else) to group by that.

For the sake of example, if `location_type` was 'Country', the output would be `{location: 'Nigeria'}`, if `location_type` was 'State', the output would be `{location: 'Lagos'}` and if `location_type` were 'City', the output would be `{location: 'Victoria Island'}` for the sample document above.

Comment: what is expected output??

Comment: Please, add a clear example of a situation when doted notation won't work, along with desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces shouldn't be a problem for dot notation. For example, the following works:

```
db.test.insert({ "a" : { "b c" : 1 } })
db.test.find({ "a.b c" : 1 })
```

For your `$project`, if you have the name of the field ("fully-qualified" name with dot notation, e.g. "a.b c" or "location.Country") stored in `location_type`, the correct form would be

```
{ "$project" : { "location" : "$" + location_type } }
```

or the equivalent using string interpolation.

I'm not sure what you mean by converting to "nested form".